# Cumulative Coupon Collecting Problem : N until $\sum_{\text{unique } x} p(x) > \epsilon$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, cumulative-distribution-functions, coupon-collector

Coupon collecting problem is well understood. But in many cases you don't care about collecting the extremely rare "coupons", but about having all the "coupons" you might care about.

E.g. imagine you are learning English and only "understand" a word once you heard it. Then standard coupon collecting problem is essentially: "how many words should I hear until I understand every word in English". As many words are very uncommon in English, a more natural question is "how many words should I listen to, so that I will understand 99% of words (not unique) that I hear". I.e. you want the cumulative distribution of all words you never heard about to be smaller than some $\epsilon$.

Specifically, let $x \in \mathcal{X}$ be a "coupon" and $\mathcal{S}_t \subseteq \mathcal{X}$ be the set of (unique) coupons seen after sampling $t$ i.i.d coupon. I was wondering if the cumulative distribution of seen coupons had already been studied, and if not how to study it:

$$CumCoupon(t) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{S}_t} p(x)$$

The questions of interests could be:

1. expected cumulative distribution seen after $t$: $\mathbb{E}[CumCoupon(t)]$
2. probability of having a cumulative distribution larger than some threshold: $p(CumCoupon(t) > 1-\epsilon)$
3. Staying in the initial example of understanding the English language, an interesting question is whether there are some approximations of the 2 previous answers for the Zipf distribution (as words are often assumed to be distributed according to zipf).

Note that compared to coupon collecting problem the above variant can also be interesting if there's an infinite (but countable) number of coupons. In the standard problem, this would of course require an infinite $t$ to collect each coupon, but here you could "cover" most of the distribution (i.e. high $CumCoupon(t)$) with a small and finite $t$ (e.g. in the case of power law / zipf distributions).

Comment: Not sure I am following.  Are you just talking about a bunch of valuable coupons plus the risk that some box you buy might contain no coupon at all (or one you don't care about)?  But that's just a minor variant of the standard Coupon Collector problem.  All the coupons you don't care about (or the No Coupon case) could be thrown into a single event.  No need to differentiate those further, right?

Comment: Do you assume that all coupon types have equal probability? If not what do you mean with "i.i.d. coupon"?

Comment: @user I'm not assuming equal probability, by iid I mean that they are sampled from an underlying distribution iid. E.g. sample each from a categorical

Comment: Is it sufficient for your purpose to know the probability to have exactly $k$ unique types of coupons after collecting $t$ coupons?

Comment: @lulu Imagine there are 4 unique types of coupons and the associated probability is [0.7,0.2,0.1,0.1]. My question is : what is the expected number of coupons to sample such that the cumulative probability of the sampled coupons is more than some threshold. 

e.g. for threshold between 0 and 0.7 the expected number of coupons is very close to 1 (because you will usually sample the most probable coupon which has probability 0.7)

e.g. for threshold = 0.8 the number will be close to 3 because you will most probably sample twice the first coupon and then an other

Comment: @user see the example above, I don't care about the number of unique types of coupons but their cumulative distribution!

Comment: What does it mean? The probability to have a certain type of coupon?